# Get posts in django by specific users [Mongonengine]

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am using mongoengine with django 1.7 and i have made a model called Projects, below is the code:

```
class Projects(Document):

user = ReferenceField(User, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
p_name = StringField(max_length=70, required=True)
author = StringField(max_length=70, required=True)
url = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
short_discription = StringField(max_length=100, required=True)
long_discription = StringField()
logo_url = StringField(max_length=200, required=False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.p_name

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.p_name = self.p_name
    return super(Projects, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('view_project', args=[self.p_name])
```

As seen in models i have referenced user in my model and it stores currently logged in user in mongodb without any problem but i can't figure out how to list the projects submitted by a particular user.

So i want to have a page as **/user/dhruv** (for example)and it will list all the projects by me.

By using **Detail View** (I don't know whether its right or not)I have managed to get one post but not more than one even after applying for loop in template:

```
class view_user(DetailView):
model = Projects
context_object_name = "project"
def get_template_names(self):
    return ["view_user.html"]

def get_object(self):
    return Projects.objects(user=self.kwargs['pk'])[0]
```

and using **ListView** here gives me an error:

```
type object 'Projects' has no attribute '_default_manager'
```

in my urls.py :

```
url(r'^user/(?P<pk>[\w\d]+)/$', view_user.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

some random post's Json format looks like this :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54e649887818f43658c85e74"),
"user" : ObjectId("54db3e5d7818f4253e5da0db"),
"p_name" : "project1",
"author" : "dhruv",
"url" : "lkn",
"short_discription" : "khb",
"long_discription" : "kjbjk",
"logo_url" : "bjk"
}
```

If anyone knows how to solve it, it will be a great help. 
P.S. : Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem fetching the `Project` instance by user's `id` value in `get_object` method. You should call [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#filter) first.

```
def get_object(self):
    return Projects.objects.filter(user=self.kwargs['pk'])[0]
```

However, your problem is more fundamental. You should subclass `ListView` not `DetailView` to get the projects of a given user. For it to work for a url like **/user/dhruv/**, you can do the following;

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^user/(?P<author>\w+)/$', UserProjectsListView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

**views.py**

```
class UserProjectsListView(ListView):
    model = Projects

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(author=self.kwargs['author'])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No change, same results only one project is being shown with **DetailView**

Comment: One more thing, i have to use object id of user in url as stored in mongodb, while on template it render's the username, is there any way to use the username in the url?
like i want to use: /user/dhruv  
but i am getting : /user/54db3e5d7818f4253e5da0db/

Comment: @DhruvNarang Yeah, all you need to do is sending `author` value through url. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Nopes that didn't worked, using my name gave me the error : **dhruv is not a valid ObjectId** moreover the author field in my models is just a string field and not doesn't link to any user.

Comment: I just want to use urls like stackoverflow's like: **http://stackoverflow.com/users/793428/ozgur** where the number '793428' is not necessary.